# cannot excute shell script with permission denied

Tags: permissions, chmod

I tried to run shell script file

```
fin.sh: 1: fin.sh: cannot create fin.log: Permission denied
```

I tried to  `sudo chmod u+x fin.sh` but still got the same error

Comment: The error is that you cannot create/overwrite the fin.log file.  Either it exists and doesn't have write permission for you or you group, or the directory in which you are trying to create the  file doesn't have write permission your you/group.

Comment: the file fin.sh is to execute a command and save the output in fin.log using `>>`

Comment: What's the directory that `fin.sh` is in? Is it mounted with `noexec`? `mount`. Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Comment: if you're not interested in security, try something like that `yourcommand | sudo tee -a fin.log`